# Angular Universal: All DOM Interaction Events Are Not Working

Tags: angular, angular-universal

So I have tried to analyze what is happening. So all of my code is rendered in the server side, the server then send only HTML code to the client. The client does not have the javascript to connect the DOM and events at client runtime.

All of my DOM click events, form submit events, etc... cannot be called on client side.

Quoting from the official documentation:

```
User events other than routerLink clicks aren't supported. You must wait for the full client application to bootstrap and run, or buffer the events using libraries like preboot, which lets you replay these events once the client-side scripts load.
```

It should work after the application is fully loaded. But in my case it is not. Here is the example of a simple case:

```
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    FooterComponent,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  selector: 'app-support',
  styleUrls: ['./support.page.scss'],
  template: `
    <ion-content>
      <section>
        
            <ion-button
              id="submitBtn"
              type="button"
              class="ion-margin"
              (click)="submit()"
            >
              {{ loading ? 'Loading...' : 'Submit' }}
            </ion-button>

      </section>
      <app-footer></app-footer>
    </ion-content>
  `,
})
export class SupportPage implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('submitBtn') submitBtn: ElementRef;

  email;
  title;
  description;

  loading = false;

  error;
  success;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId,
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    private elementRef: ElementRef
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('ASKDLASHJLDHAS');
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      const button = this.submitBtn.nativeElement;
      this.renderer.listen(button, 'click', () => {
        console.log('Button clicked');
      });
    }
  }

  async submit() {
    console.log('CLICKED');
  }
```

It is rendered well, but all interaction like button click events are not working. Nothing happens after clicking the button.